# SQL Parameter for ALL

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ado.net, oledb

I was wondering if there was a parameter in SQL for all (not *!) For example, I'm writing a search table now, and if the user does not input something in the text box, it would mean to ignore that specific parameter and display ALL of them for that field. I understand you could make separate OLEDB or SQL commands for each scenario and it would work, but I would just like to do it in one command where if the textbox is empty, I would just ignore it. So far, what this guy said I tried but didn't work... it said I had some type mismatch

http://timothychenallen.blogspot.com/2007/06/sql-server-all-values-parameters-in.html

This is my code for this portion right now

```
da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT *
                                       FROM TestQuery
                                      WHERE (VendorName = @VendorName) 
                                        AND CustomerName = @CustomerName", cs);

if (combo_VendorView.Text != "") 
  da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@VendorName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = combo_VendorView.Text.ToString();
  da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = combo_CustomerView.Text.ToString();

  dsB.Clear();
  da.Fill(dsB);
  dgv_DataLookup.DataSource = dsB.Tables[0];
```

Say if I leave txt.VendorName blank, I want to basically ignore that parameter. Thanks for your help! :)

UPDATED CODE

```
 da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * 
                                        FROM TestQuery 
                                       WHERE (CustomerName = @CustomerName 
                                           OR @CustomerName IS NULL)", cs);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = combo_CustomerView.Text.ToString();
```

i'm using ado.net visual studio 2010 if that makes a difference with oledb (access) it does fine searching with parameters but when i do not put the customer name in, it shows only the names of the columns of test query but no information... i want it to basiclly be like select * for this one column

Comment: duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745792/sql-cancel-where-on-null-parameter and many others.

Comment: sadly, most people's ways are not working... I googled this problem and the answers that are provided should work but i'm not sure why its not. this is an update of my code

Comment: What is the value of `combo_CustomerView.Text.ToString()`? It certainly isn't `DBNull.Value`, which is what you would want it to be for this to work as you intend.

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL Conditional WHERE Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485965/t-sql-conditional-where-clause)

Comment: MM first  don't know if you are having trouble for this. combo_CustomerView.Text.ToString(). It Should be combo_CustomerView.SelectedItem.Text or combo_CustomerView.SelectedValue if you want the Text of the selected item or the value. And you could try something like this da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = combo_CustomerView.SelectedItem.Text == string.Empty ? null : combo_CustomerView.SelectedItem.Text

Comment: What does `ToString()` return for a Null value?  Null or an empty (zero length) string?  If the latter, `@CustomerName IS NULL` will never be True.

Comment: @HansUp: `ToString()` doesn't return anything for a null reference; it throws a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `COALESCE` operator in this example.  If your parameter was passed in as null, or you put in logic to convert an empty string to null, you could essentially do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TestQuery
WHERE 
   VendorName = COALESCE(@VendorName,VendorName)
   AND CustomerName = COALESCE(@CustomerName, CustomerName)
```

If VendorName was NULL, it would simply check if VendorName was equal to VendorName, which would always be true.

Comment: `VendorName = COALESCE(@VendorName,VendorName)` may force a table scan to occur, rather than allowing an index lookup to happen (because it has to compute the value of the COALESCE expression for each row)

Comment: Hi, for this error i get IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005

Answer (score 1):

Use explicit `NULL` evaluation like below:

```
WHERE (Vendorname = @Vendorname OR @Vendorname IS NULL)
AND (CustomerName = @Customername OR @Customername IS NULL)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. However, when I do this I end up getting nothing. For example in my code, if I took out the customerName then i want it to display ALL customers but now I have zero customers in this view.

Comment: @Wilson - is `@Customername` passed as `NULL` when it's not filled in?

Comment: No... is it supposed to be? I just tried it and it told me @Parameter @CustomerName has no default value

Comment: @Wilson - yes, give it a default value of `NULL`.  Then the above `WHERE` clause will work as you like.

Comment: @Damien - thanks for the edit, must have accidentally hit the code block button without realizing it.

Comment: :/ it's still the same problem. I even set it when my form loads up combo_CustomerView.Text = null; and when i debugged it the locals windows said selecteditem = null and instead of getting all, I'm getting none

Comment: @Wilson - then it's not actually going to `SQL` as a `NULL`...you can modify the code to just `SELECT @Parametername` to see what it is coming across as

Comment: hey sorry for all the confusion, but i'm not sure if i understand this fully now. for the or statement, it will choose one or the other. so if there is a vendor name it'll pick the vendorname. however, if there is no vendor name, it will set the vendorname parameter to null. thereofore, the select statement will be looking for all vendor names that are equal to null... is this correct? because what i was looking for is that if there is no vendorname then you want to look for all vendornames that are not null (all of them). just wanted to clarify if thats what your code meant before

Comment: No.  The code means - if you have a `@Vendorname` **PARAMETER** set, match that.  If not, then the **PARAMETER** that you are **PASSING TO THE QUERY** will be `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

you probably need a variation on JNK's answer as I think your user input is probably coming through as empty string rather than `NULL` eg

```
WHERE (Vendorname = @Vendorname OR @Vendorname = '')
AND (CustomerName = @Customername OR @Customername = '')
```

This may of course vary from field to field.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible @CustomerName is not equal to NULL but to "" (an empty string)?

Answer (score 1):

```
combo_CustomerView.Text.ToString()  // is converting null to ''
```

so use:

```
da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM TestQuery WHERE CustomerName = @CustomerName OR @CustomerName = ''", cs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic code

```
where (col1=@param1 or @param1 is null) and (col2=@param2 or @param2 is null) and...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM TestQuery WHERE (@VendorName is null or VendorName = @VendorName) AND (@CustomerName is null or CustomerName = @CustomerName)", cs);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@VendorName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = string.isNullOrEmpty(combo_VendorView.Text) ? null : combo_VendorView.Text.ToString();
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(combo_CustomerView.Text) ? null : combo_CustomerView.Text.ToString();
dsB.Clear();                
da.Fill(dsB);
dgv_DataLookup.DataSource = dsB.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

well, maybe it is not better but it is close

```
set @VendorName = coalesce(@VendorName,'%')
set @CustomerName = coalesce(@CustomerName,'%')

SELECT * FROM TestQuery 
WHERE VendorName like @VendorName
AND CustomerName like @CustomerName
```

Now if you send it query (new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM TestQuery WHERE (VendorName = @VendorName) AND CustomerName = @CustomerName", cs)) why do you build dynamic the query?

Here an good article about that 
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/09/18/sql-conditional-where-clauses.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't do much with .NET, but I assume that `combo_CustomerView.Text.ToString()` returns the string "Null" or the empty string ("") when the combo box is empty.  What you really want to do there is assign the `NULL` literal.  In pseudocode:

```
If combo_box is empty then
    ...Parameters.Add().Value = Null
Else
    ...Parameters.Add().Value = combo_box.ToString()
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're never setting `@CustomerName` to null. In your code, if the user selects the empty entry in the `ComboBox`, the `@CustomerName` parameter will have an empty string as its value.

You need something like this:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(combo_CustomerView.Text))
{
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
}
else
{
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = combo_CustomerView.Text;
}
```

Incidentally, please don't call `.ToString()` on variables that are strings. It's akin to comparing boolean variables to `true` (or `false`).

Answer (score 0):

If the combo box is not selected, why bother with the parameter in your SQL statement's where clause at all? You already have the logic on the Vendor combo box.