# Stored Procedure with Optional DateTime Parameters in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How to write this `select` query in SQL Server when the `datetime` parameters (`@StartDate` & `@EndDate`) are optional in this stored procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prSearchEmployees]
(
    @Id INT = NULL
    ,@FullName VARCHAR(20) = NULL
    ,@Age INT = NULL
    ,@StartDate = NULL
    ,@EndDate = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT * 
   FROM Employee 
   WHERE Id = ISNULL(@Id, Id) 
     AND FullName LIKE ISNULL(@FullName + '%', FullName)
     AND Age = ISNULL(@Age, Age)
END
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
AND(
      ((NullIf(@begin, '') IS NULL)  OR CAST(ColumnDate AS DATE) >= @begin)  
    AND ((NullIf(@end, '') IS NULL)  OR CAST(ColumnDate AS DATE) <= @end)  
   )
```

covers all the options, nulls, blanks and comparisions.

Answer (score 13):

You could add two new variables at the top of your sproc.. And assign based on the ISNULL function

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prSearchEmployees]
(
 @Id INT = NULL
,@FullName VARCHAR(20) = NULL
,@Age INT = NULL
,@StartDate DATETIME = NULL
,@EndDate DATETIME = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EDate DATETIME

SET @SDate = ISNULL(@StartDate, GETDATE())
SET @EDate = ISNULL(@EndDate, GETDATE())


SELECT * FROM Employee 
     WHERE Id = ISNULL(@Id, Id) 
       AND FullName LIKE ISNULL(@FullName + '%', FullName)
       AND Age = ISNULL(@Age, Age)
       AND Date BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate
```

Comment: I was trying to use GETDATE() as an option default..and kept running into errors..this fixed that.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old post but there are alternatives that are a bit more concise. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415582/how-can-i-use-optional-parameters-in-a-t-sql-stored-procedure) outlines it perfectly. So in the previous example you would do something like

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prSearchEmployees]
(
 @Id INT = NULL
,@FullName VARCHAR(20) = NULL
,@Age INT = NULL
,@StartDate DATETIME = NULL
,@EndDate DATETIME = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN    

SELECT * FROM Employee 
     WHERE ((@Id IS NULL) OR (Id = @Id))
       AND ((@FullName IS NULL) OR (FullName LIKE @FullName + '%'))
       AND ((@Age IS NULL) OR (Age = @Age))
       AND ((@SDate IS NULL) OR (Date BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate))
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to define the datatype of `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` as `Date`. You may try like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prSearchEmployees]
(
 @Id INT = NULL
,@FullName VARCHAR(20) = NULL
,@Age INT = NULL
,@StartDate DATETIME= NULL
,@EndDate DATETIME= NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @StDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EtDate DATETIME

SET @StDate = ISNULL(@StartDate ,NOW())
SET @EtDate = ISNULL(@EndDate , NOW())

SELECT * FROM Employee 
         WHERE Id = ISNULL(@Id, Id) 
           AND FullName LIKE ISNULL(@FullName + '%', FullName)
           AND Age = ISNULL(@Age, Age)
           AND Date BETWEEN @StDate AND @EtDate
END
```

Comment: But I need to know how to handle datetime in select query in SP

Comment: @user1030181:- Updated my answer. Hope that helps now?

Answer (score 0):

**For null passing to date Field**

declare dob string

at object assignment
   stud_dtl_obj.dob = dob.Text == "" ? null : dob.Text;

at procedure assignment
   SqlHelper.MakeParam("@dob",obj_stud_dtl.dob),

inside procedure
   @dob date=NULL,