# Poor Performance on IF, OR

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a stored procedure similar to something like this:

```
SELECT a.Name AS Author,
       b.Price,
       b.PublishDate,
       b.Title,
       b.ISBN
FROM   Book b
       INNER JOIN Author a ON b.Id = a.BookId
WHERE  a.Id = @authorId OR @author = 0
```

So when the input parameter `@author` is > 0 it returns records on a specific author, if 0 it returns records on every author.

Even when I pass any values greater than 0 for @author, the performance is sub-par (though it's not terribly slow). I then notice if I remove the OR clause the stored procedure runs much faster (at least 80% faster for the same input parameter). I then try to do something like:

```
IF @author > 0 
  --select records on a specific author
ELSE
  --select everything
```

However, the performance is pretty the same as OR. Is there anyway to code something like this in a different way to gain better performance?

Comment: It's more complicated than you might think. Here is a link that goes into detail about optimising optional parameters. It has links to other even more detailed information about it also. Have a read and see if it helps.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2008 Standard or above I believe as @Sqluser said you can use an execution plan to see where the slow down is. This should also give you an index suggestion if one isn't already on the table and columns in the query

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks. I don't see the link, though.

Comment: Doh! here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415582/how-can-i-use-optional-parameters-in-a-t-sql-stored-procedure

Comment: You have authorId and author.  Do you mean to have two different?

Answer (score 2):

As Nate S said, you need an index

But in my experience, I got better performance using  `IN` rather than `OR`

```
SELECT a.Name AS Author,
       b.Price,
       b.PublishDate,
       b.Title,
       b.ISBN
FROM   Book b
       INNER JOIN Author a ON b.Id = a.BookId
WHERE  a.Id IN (@authorId, 0)
```

But always try to see your query in [execution plan](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and compare the result

**Update**

If you want conditional `WHERE` clause, you can use try these alternatives.

Using `CASE` statement

```
SELECT a.Name AS Author,
       b.Price,
       b.PublishDate,
       b.Title,
       b.ISBN
FROM   Book b
       INNER JOIN Author a ON b.Id = a.BookId
WHERE  a.Id  = CASE @authorId WHEN 0 THEN a.Id ELSE @authorId END
```

Also if you set the `@authorId = NULL` rather than 0, you can use `ISNULL` function but better not to use functions in `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT a.Name AS Author,
       b.Price,
       b.PublishDate,
       b.Title,
       b.ISBN
FROM   Book b
       INNER JOIN Author a ON b.Id = a.BookId
WHERE  a.Id  ISNULL(@authorId, a.Id)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's different logic to what is required, and `IN`'s get converted to `OR`'s anyway behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid, I think I got the point you mentioned in your comment and add some more alternatives. Hopefully can be useful for the OP.

Comment: interesting, I've never though about doing it that way!

Answer (score 1):

You should add an index to the table, including any columns in the where clause. This should add an index on the authors table ID column.

```
CREATE INDEX 'INDEX NAME'
    ON dbo.Author (ID);
```

[CREATE INDEX (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use below query and i am sure you will get your performance

```
SELECT a.Name AS Author,
           b.Price,
           b.PublishDate,
           b.Title,
           b.ISBN
    FROM   Book b
           INNER JOIN Author a ON b.Id = a.BookId
    WHERE  a.Id IN (@authorId, 0)
    option(OPTIMIZE for(@authorId =10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`Joins` hate `OR`

```
SELECT a.Name AS Author,
       b.Price,
       b.PublishDate,
       b.Title,
       b.ISBN
FROM   Book b
       INNER JOIN Author a ON b.Id = a.BookId and a.Id = @authorId 
union
SELECT a.Name AS Author,
       b.Price,
       b.PublishDate,
       b.Title,
       b.ISBN
FROM   Book b
       INNER JOIN Author a ON b.Id = a.BookId and @author = 0
```