# Is it possible to make parameter to use in where clause in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server 2012.

I have this table named myDataTable:

```
| Id | ExternalId | Subject | CMT           |    
| 1  |   3379     | damage5 | some comment7 |
| 2  |   3380     | damage3 | some comment3 | 
| 3  |   3382     | damage4 | some comment5 |
| 4  |   3381     | damage1 | some comment4 |
```

The ExternalId column is of type `Int`.

The CMT column is of type `nvarchar(max)`.

I pass to stored procedure parameter `@filterParam` of string type.

In stored procedure I need to check if `@filterParam` contains at least one letter I use `@filterParam` to filter selection with Subject column, like that :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPGeneralReport]
            @filterParam nvarchar(max),
            @CMTParam nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT      *                
FROM        myDataTable
WHERE       Subject = @filterParam AND CMT = @CMTParam
END
```

In stored procedure I need to check if `@filterParam` contains only digits I need to cast it to integer and use it in WHERE clause to filter selection with ExternalId column :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPGeneralReport]
            @filterParam nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT      *                
FROM        myDataTable
WHERE       ExternalId = @filterParam AND CMT = @CMTParam
END
```

If @filterParam is NULL I don't want to use it at all in my filter:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPGeneralReport]
            @filterParam nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT      *                
FROM        myDataTable
WHERE       CMT = @CMTParam 
END
```

I don't want to create multiple stored procedures, I want to create single procedure with optional parameter for filter.

Any idea how can I implement it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use optional parameters in a T-SQL stored procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415582/how-can-i-use-optional-parameters-in-a-t-sql-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 1):

use `OR` condition

```
WHERE (ExternalId = @filterParam OR @filterParam IS NULL)
  AND CMT = @CMTParam
```

When `@filterParam` is `NULL` the first condition will not be applied

Comment: This will work, but generally these "catch all" queries don't perform as well as they could. See: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-confuse-the-sql-server-query-optimizer/

Comment: @HoneyBadger - Parameter sniffing is kind of hit or miss

Comment: Cf the duplicate-link in comments on the question... Adding `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` in cases like these is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have 3 cases in this situation I would do something like this. Filter out the common clause first, then use condition statements on the other filter ( note I had to enable Ole Automation Procedures).

```
Create Table #Temp
(
    Id INT,
    ExternalId Int,
    [Subject] NVarChar(128),
    Comment NVarChar(128)
)

Insert Into #Temp
Values

( 1  ,   3379     ,'damage5' ,'some comment7' ),
( 2  ,   3380     ,'damage3' ,'some comment4' ),
( 3  ,   3382     ,'damage4' ,'some comment5' ),
( 4  ,   3381     ,'damage1' ,'some comment4' )

Declare @filterParam nvarchar(max) = '3380', 
        @CMTParam nvarchar(max) = 'some comment4'

Select * Into #OtherTemp
From #Temp
Where Comment = @CMTParam

IF(@filterParam IS NULL)
Begin
    Select * 
    From #OtherTemp
End
Else If (dbo.fn_regex('^\d*$',@filterParam) <> 0)
Begin
    Select * 
    From #OtherTemp
    where ExternalId = Cast(@filterParam AS Int)
End
Else
Begin
    Select * 
    From #OtherTemp
    where Subject= @filterParam
End

Drop Table #Temp
Drop Table #OtherTemp
```

Another alternative, would be to create 2 variables and perform your parsing there and use the resultant in your where clause

```
Declare @filterSubject NVarChar(128), @filterId Int

If (dbo.fn_regex('^\d*$',@filterParam) <> 0)
Begin
    SET @filterId = Cast(@filterParam AS Int)
End
Else If (@filterParam IS NOT NULL)
Begin
    SET @filterSubject =  @filterParam
End 


Select * 
From #Temp
Where (@filterId IS NULL OR ExternalId = @filterId) 
        AND (@filterSubject IS NULL OR Subject =@filterSubject)
        AND Comment = @CMTParam
```