# Remove the where clause when the value supplied is null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like auto append the where clause depending on the values supplied

Let us consider a stored procedure that contains a select query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[example]
    @From DATETIME,
    @T0 DATETIME
AS
  BEGIN TRY
      SELECT * 
      FROM footable 
      WHERE Fromdate = @From AND Todate = @TO
 END TRY
```

If the value of @From is null then the where clause must be

```
SELECT * 
FROM footable 
WHERE Todate = @TO
```

Is there any way to implement this ?

Thanks a lot for the answer. but this does not solve my problem either because `@From` and `@To` both are optional. Following this approach my code would like

```
SELECT * 
FROM footable 
WHERE (Fromdate = @From OR @From IS NULL)
  AND (Todate = @TO OR @To IS NULL)
```

Executing this results in the entire table.

Comment: The solution from Andrew is a great way to deal with this. But be careful, you can run into performance issues with this especially as the number or parameters increases. Gail Shaw has a great article on this type of thing here. https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use optional parameters in a T-SQL stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415582/how-can-i-use-optional-parameters-in-a-t-sql-stored-procedure)

Comment: I'm not sure that you're asking the right question, it looks like you want to filter data that falls between your date parameters, and this won't do that as you're matching date**times** with `@from = fromdate`. apologies if i'm wrong

Comment: @Tanner - I think you are right, but given its from `footable` I'm not sure the code is representative of a proper procedure, but just there for the question. The parameter `@T0` is then `@TO` later (Zero to O)

Comment: @Tanner : you are absolutely right. this is not the exact code am trying to write. But just there for the question.@Andrew : Absolutely right sir

Answer (score 8):

Just use normal logic to handle it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM footable 
WHERE (Fromdate = @From or @From is null)
AND Todate = @TO
option (OPTIMIZE FOR (@From UNKNOWN))
```

Edit : Added the `option` clause in, so that the query plan is optimized for an unknown value and not subject to parameter sniffing to create the initial plan in the cache. Alternatively if the usage is known, you could use a known value that generates the plan you wish.

I would choose this option first before going down the route of an `option (recompile)` - which requires the plan being generated each time regardless.

Comment: That will definitely work, however very possible that there will be performance problem. If you run this stored procedure with the NOT NULL parameter set, then it will generate the plan that would be used for NULLs also.

Comment: Yes, stable plans with this kind of query are problematic - its a valid call out, I'll add the option in to limit that

Comment: Love the `OPTIMIZE FOR` suggestion.