# Use where clause conditional in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use where clause in TableName conditional
Eg. When my variable @col1 is blank then I dont want to use where with @col1 and it should check for @col2
If @col2 is also blank then return all records.
Or else check with their respective conditions/values inside variables.

```
declare @col1 nvarchar(50)=''
declare @col2 nvarchar(50)=''
select * from TableName
where
(isnull(@col1 ,'')!='' AND col1 =@col1 )
OR
(isnull(@col2 ,'')!='' AND col2 =@col2 )
```

This returns no record when @col1 or @col2 is blank.

Instead , when both are blank it should return all records,
If any one of them contains any value then it should go for that condition.

**Edit : Dynamic Sql is not allowed**

Comment: [The “Kitchen Sink” Procedure](http://sqlsentry.tv/the-kitchen-sink-procedure/)

Comment: You don't want `!=''` you want that check to be equals.

Comment: @Andrew meaning?

Comment: @lad2025 dynamic sql is not allowed

Comment: @CSharper Do you mean Dynamic-SQL at all? You could write safe dynamic SQL - but you need to use parameters instead of hardcoding values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use optional parameters in a T-SQL stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415582/how-can-i-use-optional-parameters-in-a-t-sql-stored-procedure)

Comment: Why is dynamic SQL not allowed?  Is this homework or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
declare @col1 nvarchar(50)=''
declare @col2 nvarchar(50)=''
select * from TableName
where
(isnull(@col1 ,'')='' OR col1 =@col1 )
OR
(isnull(@col2 ,'')='' OR col2 =@col2 )
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

This is the way to handle dynamic conditions without dynamic SQL

Comment: And the performance will be really poor, especially when more condition will appear. Plus `isnull(@col1 ,'')=''` should be `@col1 IS NULL`

Comment: ah, you're right, I forgot the plan hint. let me look for it

Comment: he obviously wants '' to be treated as null

Answer (score 1):

You can trick this using LIKE

```
declare @col1 nvarchar(50)=''
declare @col2 nvarchar(50)=''
select * from TableName
where
( col1 LIKE ISNULL(@col1, '%' )
AND
( col2 LIKE ISNULL(@col2, '%' )
```

when @variable is null, it will set to filter LIKE '%' which return all values

And i changed to logic into AND, because, with assumption, if both @variable have values, then shouldn't it be display data that qualify both values? Which leads to AND logic. This may need to be consider

Answer (score 1):

create dynamic query for this

DECLARE @COL1 NVARCHAR(50)=''

DECLARE @COL2 NVARCHAR(50)=''

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(500)

SET @SQL='SELECT * FROM TABLENAME'

IF(@COL1!='')
BEGIN

SET @SQL=@SQL+' WHERE COL1='+@COL1+''

END
EXEC @SQL