# MS SQL Server + PHP : How to make a proper optional Multi Criteria Search with Multiple Tables

Tags: php, sql-server

**CONTEXT :**

I'm doing my first multi criteria search with multiple tables, using Angular 5, PHP and MS SQL server.

Basically, the user can choose between 4 fields to find a report :

- date of the report
- the topic (of the the meeting)
- the city (where the meeting was)
- the report writer

He can use one field to do his search or more to have a more precise search.

So once the user clicked on the send button, i'm sending a object to PHP with the criteria. For example, looking like this :

Object {

crd_date_reunion: null

​
crd_sujet: null

​
nom_com: "AFFOUX"

​
nom_redacteur: "cher Utilisateur"

}

**ISSUE**

So once in PHP, i've found some answers on stackoverflow like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415582/how-can-i-use-optional-parameters-in-a-t-sql-stored-procedure) to have a good algorithm to handle the optional multi criteria on several tables. So i would like to adapt it to my case. But i don't get how to adapt the CREATE PROCEDURE part with my PHP object. 
Here is what i did :

```
// I get my object here in searchCriteria
    $searchCriteria = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    $bdd = connectDb("XXX");

    $cmdSQL = "SELECT
              VUE_COMMUNE.com_nom_court,
              crd_sujet,
              crd_date_reunion,
              VUE_INFO_UTILISATEUR.NomUtilisateur
              FROM COMPTE_RENDU
              INNER JOIN VUE_INFO_UTILISATEUR ON COMPTE_RENDU.CptUtilisateur = VUE_INFO_UTILISATEUR.CptUtilisateur
              INNER JOIN VUE_COMMUNE ON COMPTE_RENDU.com_insee = VUE_COMMUNE.com_insee
              WHERE (:date IS NULL OR (crd_date_reunion = :date))
                AND (:topic IS NULL OR (crd_sujet = :topic))
                AND (:city IS NULL OR (VUE_COMMUNE.com_nom_court = :city))
                AND (:redac IS NULL OR (VUE_INFO_UTILISATEUR.NomUtilisateur = :writer))";

    $stmt = $bdd->prepare($cmdSQL);
    $stmt->bindParam(':date', $searchCriteria->crd_date_reunion, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':topic', $searchCriteria->crd_sujet, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':city', $searchCriteria->nom_com, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':writer', $searchCriteria->nom_redacteur, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetchObject()){
        $return[] = array(
            'com_insee' => formData($row->com_insee),
            'crd_sujet' => formData($row->crd_sujet),
            'crd_date_reunion' => formData($row->crd_date_reunion),
            'CptUtilisateur' => formData($row->CptUtilisateur),
            'crd_n_ref' => formData($row->crd_n_ref),
            'crd_n_affaire' => formData($row->crd_n_affaire),
            'crd_date_redac' => formData($row->crd_date_redac),
            'crd_autre_info' => formData($row->crd_autre_info)
        );
    }
```

The syntax does not seems good (maybe not adapt for MS SQL server). I've got a good ol' *"Syntax error"* concerning the WHERE part while trying it.

My adaptation seems wrong. I mean i skipped the CREATE PROCEDURE (+ the option Recompile part) because i don't understand how to use it for my case. My values are simply in my object. But I've maybe misunderstood it.
I think i need some enlightenment on the subject.

Is it doable using this ? Or do i need to try another way ? All i want is, at least, the method i should use.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

So i solved my issue by changing my way of doing. I was missing some knowledge on PHP and it take me some time to think about a simple algorithm. So this is what i wrote :

$searchCriteria = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
        $bdd = connectDb("XXXXX");

```
    $conditions = [];
    $parameters = [];

    // conditional statements for each of my fields
    if (!empty($searchCriteria->nom_com))
    {
        $conditions[] = 'VUE_COMMUNE.com_nom_court = ?';
        $parameters[] = $searchCriteria->nom_com;
    }

    if (!empty($searchCriteria->crd_date_reunion))
    {
        $conditions[] = 'crd_date_reunion = ?';
        $parameters[] = $searchCriteria->crd_date_reunion;
    }

    if (!empty($searchCriteria->crd_sujet))
    {
        $conditions[] = 'crd_sujet = ?';
        $parameters[] = $searchCriteria->crd_sujet;
    }

    if (!empty($searchCriteria->nom_redacteur))
    {
        $conditions[] = 'VUE_INFO_UTILISATEUR.NomUtilisateur = ?';
        $parameters[] = $searchCriteria->nom_redacteur;
    }


    $baseQuery = "SELECT
          VUE_COMMUNE.com_nom_court,
          crd_sujet,
          crd_date_reunion,
          NomUtilisateur,
          crd_n_ref,
          crd_n_affaire,
          crd_date_redac,
          crd_autre_info
        FROM COMPTE_RENDU
        INNER JOIN VUE_INFO_UTILISATEUR ON COMPTE_RENDU.CptUtilisateur = VUE_INFO_UTILISATEUR.CptUtilisateur
        INNER JOIN VUE_COMMUNE ON COMPTE_RENDU.com_insee = VUE_COMMUNE.com_insee";

// A condition to build the query with $conditions
    if ($conditions)
    {
        $baseQuery .= " WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $conditions);
    }

    $stmt = $bdd->prepare($baseQuery);
    $stmt->execute($parameters);
    $stmt->fetchObject();
```