# How to to write a codeblock in T-SQL "case when" statement?

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure I want to pass a parameter to.  I want to adjust my Select statement based on whether the parameter is null or contains a value.  How do I structure the Select case to have a codeblock rather than a simple assignment after the "Then" or "Else"

```
        Select Case isnull(@variable,'null') 
               when 'null' then select x from table 
               else select x from table where table.field = @variable
```

I tried putting into Begin and end but that does not seem to work

Note:  This is not a duplicate of the question about using parameters in a stored procedure- it is about a code block in a "case.. when" statement.  The usage of the parameter is part of the example, not part of the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use optional parameters in a T-SQL stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415582/how-can-i-use-optional-parameters-in-a-t-sql-stored-procedure)

Comment: Catch-all queries are *bad*. What you tried to write is equivalent to `select x from table where table.field = @variable or @variable is null` and it's still bad. You don't need such queries when you use ORMs like EF or NHibernate and LINQ.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you want to solve by using such a catch-all query?

Comment: Sending a null parameter to a report query.  If the parameter is null then exclude the requirement from the where clause otherwise include it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want [`IF-ELSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
IF @variable IS NULL 
   select x from table;
ELSE
   select x from table where table.field = @variable;
```

---

Or

```
select x from table 
where (table.field = @variable OR @variable IS NULL)
```

Comment: Second solution even better and much neater!  Thanks

Comment: @MarcL Then please accept the response as the correct answer. That is how SO works - questions are **answered** so others can find solutions.