# get all rows from db if parameter added to where clause is null

Tags: c#, sql, if-statement, null, where-clause

I have big select with where condition.

```
WHERE ADB.param1=@param
```

In Where I send param variable

```
        SqlParameter param1Param = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", param1);
        if (param1== null)
        {
            param1Param.Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
```

This code works the following way.
When query executes it always checks for `ADB.param1=param` condition and when I send DBNull.Value it gets nothing from database. 
But instead of that I want that

> if param== null

then it pay no attantion to this condition and get all rows from database. How can I achive that ?

Comment: Assuming we're talking about MS SQL Server, you cannot compare a column value with `NULL` using `=`... you have to use either `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Why don't build query dynamically? Just throw away `WHERE ADB.param1=param` from query, when `param1` is null.

Comment: can you write this part of code ? I mean check where ADB.param1=@param if @param is not null

Comment: `where (ADB.param1=@param or @param is null)`

Comment: @David - do you want the query to return ALL rows when `@param` is null... or only return rows where `param1` is null?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415582/how-can-i-use-optional-parameters-in-a-t-sql-stored-procedure).

Comment: Specify initial null value for `@param` as optional parameter should work, e.g. `@param [datatype] = NULL`. Or just use `ISNULL(@param)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one trick which doesn't even require changing your C# code:

```
WHERE ADB.param1 = COALESCE(@param, ADB.param1)
```

For non SQL `NULL` values, the `@param` must equal the `ADB.param1` column.  Otherwise, the `WHERE` clause would always be true, and would return all records.

Comment: Will not return rows where ADB.param1 is null. (If such rows exist.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return **all** rows where the `@param1` parameter is null use...

```
where (@param1 is null or ADB.param1 = @param1)
```

If you want to return only those rows where the column value of `param` is null use...

```
where ((@param1 is null and ADB.param1 is null) or ADB.param1 = @param1)
```

Comment: in such case I get all rows with ADB.param1 equaled to "0" but I want it to be what is stored in DB rows

Comment: Sorry @David, I'm not sure I understand your comment.  Are you saying my answer doesn't do what you need, or are you clarifying that it does?

Comment: where ((@param1 is null and ADB.param1 is null) or ADB.param1 = @param1) gives all rows but ADB.param1 is shown as "0" in each row.
Instead of that I want to get all rows with corresponding ADB.param1 when @param1 is null

Comment: @David, ok, try this: `where ((@param1 is null and ADB.param1 is null) or (@param1 is not null and ADB.param1 = @param1))`

Comment: thanks for the helped but I went with Tim Biegeleisen solution. It worked fine. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I assume your query is `WHERE ADB.param1=@param1`

Try with `WHERE (ADB.param1=@param1 OR @param1 IS NULL)`