# Conditionally include a line in a T-SQL WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

Honestly, I've gone over other questions posted here that mention conditional where clauses and I'm not seeing any answers that seem to work for my situation. If one does, please point me to it!

In a stored procedure called by an SSRS report, the user can select one of two values in a dropdown - say "Yes" or "No" and that goes into the variable `@color`.

In the `WHERE` clause of the sproc I need to filter differently depending on the user's selection.

So, if `@color = 'Yes'`, then I need to have a line in the `WHERE` clause that reads something like `tb1.somecolumn = 'BLUE'`. But if `@color = 'No'` then I don't need that line in the where clause at all (`tb1.somecolumn` can be any value).

How do I conditionally include a line in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use optional parameters in a T-SQL stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415582/how-can-i-use-optional-parameters-in-a-t-sql-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the check for `@color` in the WHERE as follows.

```
WHERE (@color = 'No')
OR    (@color = 'Yes' AND tb1.somecolumn = 'BLUE')
```

Explanation:

If the value of `@color` is `'No'`, then all rows are returned.
If the value of `@color` is `'Yes'`, then only the `'BLUE'` rows are returned.

Answer (score 1):

Try following condition

```
WHERE (@color = 'Yes' AND tb1.somecolumn = 'BLUE') 
   OR (@color = 'No'  AND tb1.somecolumn = tb1.somecolumn)
```