# Different "SELECT" statements base on value SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a variable `@variable 1 [bit]` which tells me either to exclude or not certain data (based on a different value) from a select statement.

Simple example I have a table (`plants`) with 2 columns :

```
Name_of_the_plant, numbers
```

I have a report in which the user should be able to declare a value `@WithoutTrees` and I should be able to present the result without the trees, based on their names(for which I have a nomenclature).

I want to be able to run the select query based in two ways based on the variable `WithoutTrees`.

1. When the bit value is 0: `SELECT * FROM Plants`
2. When the bit value is 1: `SELECT * FROM Plants where Name_of_the_plant not in ('Oak', 'Pine')`

Comment: What have you tried? This seems like a "Simple" `IF` would suffice.

Comment: use proper database tag!

Comment: Although this could be accomplished with an `OR` in the `WHERE` clause, a `UNION ALL` may perform better: `SELECT * FROM Plants WHERE @variable = 0 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM Plants WHERE @variable = 1 AND Name_of_the_plant NOT IN ('Oak', 'Pine');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use optional parameters in a T-SQL stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415582/how-can-i-use-optional-parameters-in-a-t-sql-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dd8c9/26)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Plants(
    Name_of_the_plant VARCHAR(255),
    numbers INT
);

INSERT INTO Plants(Name_of_the_plant,numbers)VALUES('Oak', 100),
                                                  ('Pine', 56),
                                                  ('XXX', 90)
```

**Query 1**:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @variable1 bit 
SET @variable1=1

IF (@variable1 = 0)
BEGIN 
SELECT * FROM Plants
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM Plants where Name_of_the_plant NOT IN ('Pine','Oak')
END
END
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dd8c9/26/0)**:

```
| Name_of_the_plant | numbers |
|-------------------|---------|
|               XXX |      90 |
```

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question, what if I want have 2 variables(again bit) and I want to specify the select statements based on every combination between "True" and "False" in those variables? Could I write "If (@variable1 = 0) AND (@variable2 = 0)"?

Comment: @StoychoDimitrov what are your conditions ?

Comment: Using the same example: The user is choosing to view report with all plants, or select two variables "@WithoutTrees" and "@WithoutFertilePlants" . The resu;ts that is received by the "SELECT" statement must be based on the both values. Both could be "true", both could be "false" or they could be different "true" and "false".