# Passing null parameter to the stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

In my `Create` method, I am using a stored procedure to `INSERT INTO` my SQL Server database. Sometimes, fields such as `Comment` will be left blank. However, it does not work as I wished.

Firstly, this is how my method looks like:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string sql = "CreateTask";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                .....................

                parameter = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@Condition",
                    Value = task.Condition,
                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar
                };
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                .....................
```

When `task.Condition` is null, `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` gets the following error:

> : 'Procedure or function 'CreateTask' expects parameter '@Condition', which was not supplied.'

However, the columns in the table are set to allow null values.

[image]

The stored procedure also looks like this:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateTask]
    @Name        NVARCHAR(50),
    @IsGate   BIT,
    @Condition Varchar(450),
    @Precondition       Varchar(450),
    @Comments       Varchar(450),
    @StartDate       DateTime,
    @EndDate       DateTime,
    @AssignedTo    Nvarchar(450),
    @PhaseId int 
AS
BEGIN
    Insert Into dbo.Tasks (Name, IsGate, Condition, Precondition, Comments, StartDate, EndDate, AssignedTo, PhaseId, InProgress, Finished, Aborted) Values (@Name, @IsGate, @Condition, @Precondition, @Comments, @StartDate, @EndDate, @AssignedTo, @PhaseId, '0', '0', '0')
END
```

Therefore, what should I tweak in order to allow the stored procedure to get null values?

Comment: Declare stored procedure's parameters as optional. [For reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415582/how-can-i-use-optional-parameters-in-a-t-sql-stored-procedure)

Comment: If the value of the data is null you can assign `DBNull.Value` instead.

Comment: @Crowcoder If I use, for example, `command.Parameters.Add(parameter, DBNull.Value);`, I get an error saying `cannot convert from System.DBNull to System.Data.SqlDbType`

Comment: @Questieme so don't use that overload, do it exactly like in your example where you set `Value`.

Comment: @Crowcoder Oh, silly me. I edited the code to this: `DBNull.Value = task.Condition` and now the error I'm getting is: `a static readonly field cannot be assigned to` , `invalid initializer member declarator`

Comment: Declare the parameter as `@Condition varchar(450) = null`, if you don't add the parameter with `command.ParametersAdd` than it will be NULL.

Comment: You can use a single statement to create the parameter, add it to the `Parameters` collection and set the value while converting C# `null` to SQL `null` as needed: `command.Parameters.Add("@Condition", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 450).Value = task.Condition ?? (object)DBNull.Value;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to assign `DBNull.Value` to the `SqlParameter` if the data is null and you want to insert `null` into the database:

```
parameter = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "@Condition",
    Value = (object)task.Condition ?? DBNull.Value,
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar
};
```

Comment: a 'default', or optional parameter as @Yurii suggested is much better!

Comment: `Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'DBNull'`

Comment: @Luuk not necessarily. You can't assume you always want a default on a stored procedure parameter.

Comment: @Crowcoder: that's why you only specify it when it's needed.(it the parameter IS optional)

Comment: @Questieme appologies, I forgot to cast to object. You could also set it outside if that looks too hacky.

Comment: @Luuk I stand by my original comment, it may not be appropriate to allow blind nulls, you might want callers to be explicit.

Comment: @Questieme as also noted you could set the default in the stored procedure itself but only you can know if that is what you want to happen. It has the advantage of not needing a code change.

Answer (score -1):

If Condition , data type is used as string in C#, then while passing this parameter as `null` to the procedure will give this error.

So better to user some ternary operator like this

```
 com.Parameters.Add("@Condition", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =                         
                    (object.Condition== null) ? string.Empty : object.Condition;
```

I was also facing the same issue, but `DB.Null` did not work in my case.

My case is like:

```
 com.Parameters.Add("@RentalCounterProduct1EquipmentCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =                         
                    (obgKafkaStagingRentalSource.RentalCounterProduct1EquipmentCode == null) ? string.Empty : obgKafkaStagingRentalSource.RentalCounterProduct1EquipmentCode;
```

Comment: The op wants to insert a NULL into the db. This will insert an empty string instead. As a rule, if a db column supports null, null should be used, not empty string. The absence of something is different from empty string in comparison as well as db optimizations.