# SQL Server Null or missing values in the stored procedure's parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE oc.add_discount (@course_id INT = '',
                                @level VARCHAR(100) = '',
                                @language VARCHAR(100) = '',
                                @series_name VARCHAR(100) = '',
                                @discount DECIMAL(5,4) = 0.0)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @level = ISNULL(@level,'')
    SET @language = ISNULL(@language,'')
    SET @series_name = ISNULL(@series_name,'')
    UPDATE oc.price
    SET discount = @discount,
    --discount based always on the original price
        price = price/(1-discount)*(1-@discount)
    WHERE 
        (@course_id NOT IN (SELECT course_id FROM oc.courses)
            OR course_id IN (@course_id)) AND
        (@level NOT IN (SELECT level FROM oc.level)
            OR course_id IN (SELECT c.course_id 
                    FROM oc.courses c
                    JOIN oc.level l ON c.level_id = l.level_id 
                    WHERE l.level = LOWER(@level))) AND
        (@language NOT IN (SELECT language FROM oc.language)
            OR course_id IN (SELECT c.course_id
                    FROM oc.courses c
                    JOIN oc.language l ON c.language_id = l.language_id
                    WHERE l.language = UPPER(LEFT(@language,1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(@language,2,LEN(@language))))) AND
        (@series_name NOT IN (SELECT series_name FROM oc.series)
            OR course_id IN (SELECT c.course_id
                    FROM oc.courses c
                    JOIN oc.series s ON c.series_id = s.series_id
                    WHERE s.series_name = @series_name))
    IF @@ROWCOUNT<1
        RAISERROR('Ooops something went wrong. No discount has been added. Avoid NULL or missing values, use '' instead!', 16, 0);
END;
```

My problem is that the procedure is working properly in most of the cases however if a parameter is null it doesn't update anything and if a parameter in the middle is missing I get an error. I managed the problem with an error message but I would like to find a more elegant solution. Could anyone help me,please?

```
EXEC oc.add_discount 0.1, 1                       ---- this query gives 10% discount for course ID 1
EXEC oc.add_discount 0.1, '', 'beginner', '', ''  ---- this query 10% discount for every beginner course
EXEC oc.add_discount 0.1, NULL, 'beginner', '','' ---- "0 rows affected"
EXEC od.add_discount 0.1, ,'beginner', ,          ---- "Incorrect syntax near ','."
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use optional parameters in a T-SQL stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415582/how-can-i-use-optional-parameters-in-a-t-sql-stored-procedure)

Comment: There are four examples underneath with the results after the queries. Or maybe I don't understand what you are asking?

Comment: "works" is not an example. I meant sample input data and output data, or in this case an indication which rows would be affected, or at least a row count.

Comment: I see,sorry. 
`EXEC oc.add_discount 0.1, 1 ` ----this one gives 10% discount for course ID 1

`EXEC oc.add_discount 0.1, '', 'beginner', '', '' ` ----this one gives 10% discount for every beginner course

Comment: `NULL <> ''` ;-)

Comment: I know but what does it have to do with it? I could write 'unknown' instead of '' but the problem is the same.

Comment: @KatalinSzeghalmi . . . You have neglected to describe what behavior you want when a parameter is `NULL`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that's why I have this part:
`SET @level = ISNULL(@level,'')
    SET @language = ISNULL(@language,'')
    SET @series_name = ISNULL(@series_name,'')`
How else could I do? could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Generally it is preferred to call parameters by name: In this way, you can call the parameters in any order.

  ```
  EXEC oc.add_discount @course_id = 1, @level=''...
  ```
- If you want to call procedure using ordered parameters:

  - you have to pass the parameters in order and you can skip the subsequent parameters(provided they have got default values).
  - you cannot skip parameters in the middle.

Coming to your question, if you want to skip the middle parameters and call them with default values, instead of hardcoding them.

```
EXEC oc.add_discount 0.1, DEFAULT, 'beginner', DEFAULT, DEFAULT
```

Or, if you want to pass null values, pass null values and handle them inside the procedure

```
EXEC oc.add_discount 0.1, NULL, 'beginner', NULL, NULL
```

In your case, you are handling it twice. I would suggest you to do in the below way.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE oc.add_discount (@course_id INT = NULL,
                                @level VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
                                @language VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
                                @series_name VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
                                @discount DECIMAL(5,4) = NULL)
as

    SET @level = ISNULL(@level,'')
    SET @language = ISNULL(@language,'')
    SET @series_name = ISNULL(@series_name,'')
    SET @discount = ISNULL(@discount ,0.0)
```

- If you don't pass value, it is filled with NULL default value and set accordingly.

```
EXEC oc.add_discount 0.1
```

- If you want to pass default value in the middle, call with `DEFAULT` parameter

```
EXEC oc.add_discount 0.1,DEFAULT,1,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,1
```

Comment: Thanks,dealing with NULLs solved. :) However the last query has too many arguments and doesn't work. Did you mean `EXEC od.add_discount 0.1, DEFAULT,'beginner',DEFAULT , DEFAULT`? If I run this one it gives me this error: **Could not find stored procedure 'od.add_discount'.** Do you have any explanation for this?

Comment: I just gave example. It seems your schema is oc. you have to call `oc.add_discount`. You need to pass right number of parameters

Comment: Omg it was just a typo and I almost went crazy. :D Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, you want to skip some parameters for some scenarios. I recommend you to use the following approach to skip parameters when executing the Stored Procedure.

```
EXEC od.add_discount @level='',@language='beginner'
```

However, as per your example, I don't recommend to use quotations for INT parameter. You should consider using NULL instead.

Comment: If I use NULL it doesn't do anything, that's why I used empty string instead.

Comment: Then I guess you haven't addressed the null properly.

Comment: What you mean? Could you explain me this?

Comment: @KatalinSzeghalmi - This is a separate question. Kindly start a new topic.