# SQL Server stored procedure optionally return all records or filter based on parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that returns the data by passing a parameter to it, similar to:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MySP (@ID VARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
  
    SELECT *
    FROM mytable t
    WHERE t.ID = @ID
END
```

I need to have this option that the stored procedure returns all records if passing no parameters, while getting specific records by passing the parameter to it.

I wonder how my stored procedure should be modified for that? I appreciate everyone's help!

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415582/how-can-i-use-optional-parameters-in-a-t-sql-stored-procedure) or use `IF` with `BEGIN` and `END` as filter/switch

Comment: `t.ID = @ID or @ID is null`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like (not tested):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MySP (@ID VARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF @ID = '' OR @ID IS NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM mytable t
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM mytable t
    WHERE t.ID = @ID
END
 
END
```