# LIKE and NULL in WHERE clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, where-clause, sql-like

I have a store procedure which i have planned to use for search and get all values.

**Scenario:**
If the parameter passed is `NULL` it should return all the values of the table and if the parameter passed is not `NULL` it should return the values according to the condition which is in LIKE.

//Query:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_GetAllCustomerDetails]
(
@Keyword nvarchar(20) =  null
)
As
Begin

Select CustomerId,CustomerName,CustomerTypeName,CustomerCode,CategoryName,CustomerMobile,CustomerEmail,CustomerAddress,CustomerCity,CustomerState,Pincode
from tblCustomerMaster CM
inner join dbo.tblCustomerTypeMaster CTM on CTM.CustomerTypeId = CM.CustomerType
inner join dbo.tblCategoryMaster CCM on CCM.CategoryId= CM.CustomerCategory
where CustomerName like '%'+@Keyword+'%'
```

In the above query it returns no values when i execute since the `NULL` is assumed as `string` by `SQL`, so what should i write in the `where` clause to get the desired output?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924400/like-does-not-accept-null-value

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use condition like this in you `where` clause

```
where @Keyword is null or CustomerName like '%' + @Keyword + '%'
```

Comment: Be carefully when use query like that because you will run in to performance issues. When you use @Keyword is null OR something, all indexes is not used. The query will slower. Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161573/how-to-optimize-the-use-of-the-or-clause-when-used-with-parameters-sql-server

Comment: you may or may not run into performance issues with query. There're some techniques to avoid this, but I believe this question is more about generic where syntax

Answer (score 4):

I just want to point out another way of solving this problem.  The issue is that the default value for `@KeyWord` is `NULL`.  If you change the default to `''`, then the problem goes away:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_GetAllCustomerDetails]
(
@Keyword nvarchar(20) = ''
)
```

Any non-NULL customer name would then be like '%%'.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `SET @Keyword = coalesce(@Keyword,'')` to your procedure like this :

```
 ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_GetAllCustomerDetails]
(
@Keyword nvarchar(20) =  null
)
As
Begin
SET @Keyword = coalesce(@Keyword,'')

Select CustomerId,CustomerName,CustomerTypeName,CustomerCode,CategoryName,CustomerMobile,CustomerEmail,CustomerAddress,CustomerCity,CustomerState,Pincode
from tblCustomerMaster CM
inner join dbo.tblCustomerTypeMaster CTM on CTM.CustomerTypeId = CM.CustomerType
inner join dbo.tblCategoryMaster CCM on CCM.CategoryId= CM.CustomerCategory
where CustomerName like '%'+@Keyword+'%'
```

Comment: don't recomment to do this. You'll end up with quere `where CustomerName like '%%'` and this is not the same as plain select all from table.

Comment: @RomanPekar This will only exclude `NULL` values, right ? or will there be any more difference ?