# Does the SQL'%' wild card character capture null values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Recently I've come across a problem with a query that isn't returning everything that it's expected to return. Part of the query which selects by a condition is as follows:

```
AND field LIKE 
    CASE WHEN @val = 1 THEN
        '%' 
    ELSE
        'N'
    END
```

Now, when @val is 1, I'd expect this piece of code to essentially do nothing, as in the condition to basically accept any value what so ever, including null values.

Am I wrong about this? And if so, does anyone have a solution? I was thinking something along the lines of

```
AND field LIKE 
    CASE WHEN @val = 1 THEN
        '%' OR ISNULL(field)
    ELSE
        'N'
    END
```

However SQL doesn't work like that, but that's basically what I wish to accomplish.

Thanks all, and sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: `ISNULL`, on SQL Server, requires 2 parameters. The first is the NULLable value,. and the second is the value to return if the first has a value of `NULL` (this second value could also, have a value of `NULL`, which would return `NULL`).

Comment: `NULL` essentially has no value, so it can't be equal to or like anything, even a wildcard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on what you're trying to accomplish, it seems your query could be optimized to this:

```
AND (@val = 1 OR field = 'N')
```

There doesn't seem to be a reason for the `LIKE`.

**UPDATE**

Since you are trying to understand the behavior of `LIKE` and `CASE` moreso than working with existing queries, here are some variations of the accepted answer.

To use `CASE` within the `LIKE`, you have to use something like `COALESCE` to handle the null case as well.

```
COALESCE(Field, '') LIKE (CASE WHEN @val = 1 THEN '%' ELSE 'N' END)
```

Otherwise, you can use the `LIKE` within the `CASE` (like accepted answer), but probably personal preference that this seems easier to read:

```
1 = (CASE WHEN @val = 1 OR Field LIKE 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: Exactly. Check out this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18683575/44522

Comment: Except, maybe, the original author ***wanted*** to exclude NULLs? ;)

Comment: Original undocumented intent is very hard to decipher :)

Comment: Perhaps. The intent code shared seemed to be that the author thought NULL should be included. Otherwise, original code would have worked as it already excluded NULL.

Comment: I don't expect you all to read my life story, but I stated that I expected the query to include null values, hence I didn't want to exclude nulls.
However, that's why I asked if the % wildcard did exclude nulls. :)

Comment: Updated answer with variations to use `CASE`/`LIKE` as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

`field LIKE '%'` does not match null.  CASE expressions must return a single type of result, I like int in most of mine.

```
AND 1 = CASE
    WHEN @val = 1 THEN 1
    WHEN field like 'N' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question and providing a solution to fix my problem.

Comment: `field like 'N'` is essentially the same as `field = 'N'`, though there are some slight differences between SQL `LIKE` and `=`. If the intent was for `field` to be 'N', then an `=` would be clearer than a `LIKE`. `LIKE` in SQL usually implies that the OP would want 'N', 'No', 'Ain't Gonna Pick Me' to all match the condition.

Comment: Sure, `=` is clearer than `LIKE` for this match.  I felt that drawing attention to that was drawing attention away from other important knowledge.  I wanted to focus on how LIKE works with nulls and how to write clear CASE expressions that return a single type as required.  That knowledge was requested.

Comment: NOTE: In my above comment, I should have added that _**IN THIS INSTANCE**_ they are essentially the same. However, `LIKE` and `=` can behave _very_ differently, especially where trailing spaces, collation and wildcard characters in the data come into play.

Comment: It's kind of a ho-hum pattern of communication in stackoverflow where we talk about comments in the comments rather than about the answer.

Comment: :-) True. Though comments sometimes do have some good nuggets of information for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (assuming that `field` is `varchar` or `nvarchar`) -

```
AND ISNULL(field,'') LIKE 
    CASE WHEN @val = 1 THEN
        '%'
    ELSE
        'N'
    END
```

Comment: [NULLIF returns a null value if the two specified expressions are equal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql)

Comment: oops its my mistake.. it is `ISNULL` and not `NULLIF`